# Bluetooth device list

Tags: bluetooth

I recently went on  a trip with my RPi several hundred miles from were i live and i was surprised to see that when i ran `bluetoothctl` then `devices` it still showed devices from my house

[image: device list]

[image: device list at my house]

It is possible but **extremely** unlikely that they have the exact same device list as i have at home but, as i don't think they do what would cause this behavior?

Top picture is there bottom is at my house.

Comment: I believe the system caches known devices.

Comment: Second that. I think if you check /var/lib/bluetooth you should find records of all the cached devices. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580347/programmatically-removing-all-bluetooth-devices-on-the-linux-command-line

Comment: Third that.  My phone does this; if I check under "bluetooth" I get a list of everything I've ever paired with and not deleted.  Or else, presuming you are old enough to remember [Maximum Overdrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Overdrive), you might want to check behind you...under the chair...in the next room... *Who made who?*

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing those devices because your raspberry pi is keeping a record of all the devices you have ever paired with.

Comment: This is a weird feature, why does it list devices that are not able for connection? How is it possible to list devices that are actually avaiable?